# Why google cache with AspectJ is slow while SpringCaching is faster

Tags: java, caching, guava, aspectj, spring-cache

I was reading about caching mechanism and created a sample project of EhCache using SpringCaching with AspectJ and benchmark it against google cache using SpringCaching with AspectJ. What i found, is bit surprising to me.

Note:- Spring Caching I meant, methods are annotated with @Cacheable/@Caching annotations.

SpringCaching with AspectJ is fater but on the other hand google cache with AspectJ performs slower. Below are mean of the times they took to process requests:-

```
GoogleCacheWithoutAspect 
1.262323232 ms

GoogleCacheWithAspect
5.205010101 ms

SpringCachingWithoutAspect
3.08548 ms

SpringCachingWithAspect
2.77782 ms
```

As i'm newbie, so i'm also wanted to confirm, why should one use AspectJ with Spring Caching, how does AspectJ make caching faster.

I also follow the below post, but still not sure, does AspectJ really improves the caching performance.
http://architects.dzone.com/articles/cacheable-overhead-spring-0

Comment: As soon as you get down that low in latency you get into the realm of micro-benchmarking. With out seeing your benchmark code its most likely just random JIT warm up time issues your seeing. Google Java micro-benchmark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> still not sure, does AspectJ really improves the caching performance

The figures from the [article](http://architects.dzone.com/articles/cacheable-overhead-spring-0) clearly show that AspectJ is far superior (and on eye-level with or even better than manual caching) regarding runtime overhead in comparison to Spring AOP. This is because:

- Spring uses dynamic proxies (i.e. subclasses or interface implementations dyamically created during runtime) and always introduces call chaining due to each call being routed through a proxy in order to implement AOP interception behaviour. This is true for Java dynamic proxies (used for interfaces) as well as CGLIB proxies (used for classes).
- AspectJ does not need any proxies because it is weaving optimised code directly into the original classes via bytecode instrumentation. This is done during compile-time or optionally once per JVM start-up during class-loading. This is fast and efficient.

Comment: But why does **google cache with AspectJ** performs slower  than **google cache without AspectJ**. any idea?

Comment: I have insufficient information to hypothesise, not having seen your code. And is AspectJ really native AspectJ or is it rather Spring AOP? Please share a repo on GitHub for me to inspect.